# HTML Parser into DOM in Ruby

Tags: html, ruby, dom, html-parsing, nokogiri

Is there any HTML parser in Ruby that reads HTML document into a DOM Tree and represents HTML tags as DOM elements?

I know Nokogiri but it doesn't parse HTML into DOM tree.

Comment: Nokogiri's default looks an awful lot like a DOM tree to me, why do you say it isn't?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Despite your remark, Nokogiri is the way to go:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<body><p>Hello, worlds!</body>')
```

It parses even invalid HTML and returns a DOM tree:

```
>> doc.class
=> Nokogiri::HTML::Document
>> doc.root.class
=> Nokogiri::XML::Element
>> doc.root.children.class
=> Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet
>> doc.root.children.first.content
=> "Hello, worlds!"
```

Comment: I will look more into it. Thank you.

Comment: @qlinux you’re welcome! If you bump into more questions, just post them on SO and tag them with nokogiri, I am following that tag. Nokogiri is a powerful and fun gem!

Comment: @the-tin-man thanks for the edit! As you’re already up to it, could you possibly reopen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769217 so I can provide that gentleman with the answer he’s looking for? :)

Comment: You will need to `gem install nokogiri` if not already present (distributed with rails), and `require 'nokogiri'` in your code.