# How Nokogiri parse a HTML-form string into DOM

Tags: html, ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

I have been looking into Nokogiri source code but haven't got how Nokogiri parse a string into Elements. The source code can be found here:

https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/tree/master/lib/nokogiri

For example: I have a string:

```
raw = "<html> <body> body <div>this is div </div> </body> <html>"

Nokogiri::HTML(raw)
=> 
#(Document:0x4d0c786 {
  name = "document",
  children = [
    #(DTD:0x4d0bc6e { name = "html" }),
    #(Element:0x4cfa46e {
      name = "html",
      children = [
        #(Element:0x4cf9bfe {
          name = "body",
          children = [
            #(Text "body"),
            #(Element:0x4cf9348 {
              name = "div",
              children = [ #(Text "this is div")]
              })]
          })]
      })]
  })
```

I look into the `nokogiri / lib / nokogiri / xml / sax`, I don't see anywhere how it interpret the html string. When I try reading the source code, I realize in the above output, there is data type `Element` but I don't see anywhere in the source code that declare `class Element`.

In general, can anyone help me explain how Nokogiri parse a string into a data structure above ?

Comment: Nokogiri uses [libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/), a native C library. It is libxml2 that's actually doing the parsing.

Comment: thanks. do you know how ruby interacts with libxml2 ?

Comment: You'd probably have to look at the C stuff for that (https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/tree/master/ext/nokogiri)

Comment: You asked a very similar question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791789/html-parser-into-dom-in-ruby. Why didn't that selected answer help? How it does it is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: That question asked about any tools existed that does parsing HTML into DOM. ,Here I want to go more deeply to understand how it works :-).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, Nokogiri uses libxml2 to handle the actual parsing. This is done using a native (read: coded in C) Ruby extension. Ruby has a [well documented](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ext_ruby.html) standard interface for building native extensions. [Here is a good guide](http://blog.jcoglan.com/2012/07/29/your-first-ruby-native-extension-c/).